# In vertica, Is there any way to access admintools without admin rights?

Tags: database, vertica

In vertica, Is there any way to access admintools without admin rights?. How to find nodes and cluster configure details in normal user in vertica?

Answer (score 0):

You might have already tried it.
You must have access to the Linux shell level on one of the Vertica nodes, as a user that is allowed to write to `/opt/vertica/log/adminTools.log` . And that is, by default, `dbadmin`.

I would regard it as quite a security risk to tamper with the permissions around that, really.

A good start would be:

```sh
$ vsql -U <user> -w <pwd> -h 127.127.127.128 -d dbnm -x -c "select * from host_resources"
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------+-----------------------------------------
host_name                      | 127.127.127.128
open_files_limit               | 65536
threads_limit                  | 7873
core_file_limit_max_size_bytes | 0
processor_count                | 1
processor_core_count           | 2
processor_description          | Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
opened_file_count              | 7
opened_socket_count            | 10
opened_nonfile_nonsocket_count | 7
total_memory_bytes             | 8254820352
total_memory_free_bytes        | 1034915840
total_buffer_memory_bytes      | 523386880
total_memory_cache_bytes       | 5516861440
total_swap_memory_bytes        | 2097147904
total_swap_memory_free_bytes   | 2097147904
disk_space_free_mb             | 425185
disk_space_used_mb             | 76682
disk_space_total_mb            | 501867
system_open_files              | 1440
system_max_files               | 798044
-[ RECORD 2 ]------------------+-----------------------------------------
host_name                      | 127.127.127.129
open_files_limit               | 65536
threads_limit                  | 7873
core_file_limit_max_size_bytes | 0
processor_count                | 1
processor_core_count           | 2
processor_description          | Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
opened_file_count              | 7
opened_socket_count            | 9
opened_nonfile_nonsocket_count | 7
total_memory_bytes             | 8254820352
total_memory_free_bytes        | 1836150784
total_buffer_memory_bytes      | 487129088
total_memory_cache_bytes       | 4774060032
total_swap_memory_bytes        | 2097147904
total_swap_memory_free_bytes   | 2097147904
disk_space_free_mb             | 447084
disk_space_used_mb             | 54783
disk_space_total_mb            | 501867
system_open_files              | 1408
system_max_files               | 798044
-[ RECORD 3 ]------------------+-----------------------------------------
host_name                      | 127.127.127.130
open_files_limit               | 65536
threads_limit                  | 7873
core_file_limit_max_size_bytes | 0
processor_count                | 1
processor_core_count           | 2
processor_description          | Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
opened_file_count              | 7
opened_socket_count            | 9
opened_nonfile_nonsocket_count | 7
total_memory_bytes             | 8254820352
total_memory_free_bytes        | 1747091456
total_buffer_memory_bytes      | 531447808
total_memory_cache_bytes       | 4813959168
total_swap_memory_bytes        | 2097147904
total_swap_memory_free_bytes   | 2097147904
disk_space_free_mb             | 451444
disk_space_used_mb             | 50423
disk_space_total_mb            | 501867
system_open_files              | 1408
system_max_files               | 798044
```

In general, check the Vertica docu for system tables and information available there....